# Why doesn't my kitchen range hood effectively exhaust fumes?

Tags: kitchens, hood, range-hood

We had a Hauslane P18 range hood installed and it is never able to suck well. Most of the cooking fumes escape with the front burner, and even when cooking with the back burners smoke manages to escape.

The hood is exhausting directly back, rather than through the top. The home builder had installed a metallic box/cavity behind the drywall that the hood is blowing into (previously a microwave), not a direct duct to the outside. And that metallic box has an opening to the outside.

When the hood is on, I can feel the wind blowing on the exterior vent of the house. I've tried opening windows since we don't have a makeup air fan with no changes to the suction.

We're assuming the metallic box is the reason why the hood is not working efficiently, but could there be other reasons?

We're stumped

Comment: Without photos and dimensions of ducts, box etc, it is inviting opinions, which is off-topic

Comment: What you’re calling a ‘metallic box’ is also a duct. More details, please.

Comment: You shouldn't get actual *smoke* from the vast majority of cooking. Cooker hoods on maximum fan (and noise) mode might just about be able to deal with slightly burning something, but at normal levels they won't keep up - but that shouldn't happen often

Comment: *exterior vent of the house* for a MW would be like 4" square. For a real range hood you need like an 8", and it has to be closer to 1000 cfm then it is to 500.

Comment: @isherwood smoke isn't defined as gaseous, smoke is particulate matter.  And it's a valid concern, which you do get from gas stoves. But I'm sure it's not what the OP is talking about, because they can detect their "smoke".  We also don't know that they have gas - I wouldn't use "burner" to refer to an electric ring, but people do.

Answer (score 1):

See my [recent writeup](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/287262/35141) on range hood effectiveness. I think many folks overestimate what such a device can be expected to do. Even when running at full blast, the total area that would need to be scavenged is too large for complete exhausting of all offensive gases, especially when human activity and open windows are considered.

That said, if your ducting is not adequate, or if it has characteristics that impede proper flow, the effectiveness of the unit will be greatly diminished.